# jacoco code coverage on integration test cases without sources

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage, jacoco

I have collected jacoco code coverage on integration test cases. Now I want to upload integration code coverage in Sonar 6.3. Since these are integration coverage results, source code is not available. Is it possible to show integration code coverage results into Sonar by any api/any other methos. If it possible, please share the relevant documentation. It would help me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update an existing analysis. Your only option is to run the integration tests *before* analysis, and feed the report into the analysis.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand. How can I update sonar qube with code coverage results on integration tests (through Jacoco execution file)? Is there any api which can  update integration code coverage in sonarqube? My limitation is source code on application is not available.

Comment: You cannot _update_ SonarQube. You can only feed data during the initial analysis.